# Hide information from my CV?

Tags: ethics, application, cv

I'm preparing my application to send it to my dream university (it's located in Germany), and my problem is:
Since I'm coming from a country that facing civil war (Syria), I had real troubles in high school (no electricity power and such things), so I had poor results,So I had entered college I don't like (I want to study CS) also I fall in some troubles with my classmates because I came from a different culture, the general atmosphere was not friendly at all, studying with all that was very hard for me, so I have poor results again, after all I take my decision I left the college and retake the high school exam and I have got ~80%.
So the question is: should I mention that I have 2 high school certificates and I got out the college with poor results or just mention my second high school certificate, is that ethical? and is that will effect on my new university decision?

Just to get the whole picture : I had studied hardly for my second high school exam and I lost a lot of time with no academic results, in other hand I'm a good programmer, book worm, research enthusiasm, I want to continue my studies to get the PhD, I have industry experience in the field, and working on some projects as a volunteer to help my community.

I'm in bad situation and my academic future is depends on what to do now, so any advice are welcome.

**Edit** (clarification): I'm going as undergraduate student.

Comment: Hiding information in your CV that is later discovered gives them ground to terminate you after you enter the program.

Comment: Frankly this is not a problem, because they won't know if I don't mention it, my problem is: what to do from ethically point (and why)?, and how this will effect the university decision (what they think about me)?

Comment: I would look into programs that are specifically meant to cater to people in situations like yours. Schools often have scholarships or at least "entrance awards" for underprivileged students. Typically, you have to write an essay and convince them that you fit their description of "underprivileged" and sometimes appear for an interview. If they believe you and believe you will benefit from the program, you won't have to worry about applying through the traditional channels.

Comment: @fredsbend the university that I'm applying for doesn't have such kind of programs, but yes what I think I need is "entrance awards", but with a look to my financial situation I don't need scholarship, I like to let it to somebody really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may vary with culture (I'm not sure how Germany views such things).  In the United States, your story about overcoming adversity and persevering may be very compelling to the admissions committee.  Universities rarely select only the best candidates based on grades.  They give extra consideration to those that may have had a tough time early on because of circumstances beyond their control.  So it may actually help you to talk about your history and not to hide it.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that hiding information in anything of this nature - a CV, a resume, and so on - is always suspicious and usually unethical.

I would provide a brief explanation in your personal statement.  Given it has to do with a situation that is unquestionably out of your control, some universities might forgive less-than-exemplary marks.

Getting a masters degree before a PhD could improve your situation further - in this way, you can further prove yourself as a good programmer and book worm who wants to do research.  Naturally the CS field wants more than just these traits, but you seem willing to learn.

Edit: If you're going for an undergraduate degree, all the better!  Simply proving your aptitude should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, what I'm really worried about is proving my aptitude (and get a chance to do that), I think ~80% doesn't mean much for universities with high rates of applications.
my second question was:
Is mention my previous experience in education in CV make the things better or not? from technical point.

Comment: I believe Mark, above, gave you a good answer on this point.  Your previous experiences may matter more or less depending on the school and how forthright you are about them.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you choose to hide/omit something is up to you and, in my opinion, unless it is pertinent or explicitly asked not unethical. That being said, you must be aware of a few things, firstly they may at some point in time discover your omitting. What do you think will be their reaction? Mind you this could have AFTER graduation, perhaps when you've won some prestigious award and finally the truth come to light, what do you think would happen and are you ok with that scenario? Secondly, don't assume what they will say or how they will react to information you have or have not given them. You never know how somebody will react until you tell them and it may well work in your favor.

Comment: In Germany you are required to give information on all previous schooling. Failing to do so can cause you to lose any degrees earned if it is discovered (and this applies to any level -- undergraduate or graduate). Be honest, and explain the problem in an additional letter.